# Filter items in a consumer web part using multiple filter values from a provider web part

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I want to be able to filter down an Announcements list by multiple values coming from a Current User Filter web part. I managed to connect the consumer and provider web part (using this http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/connect-a-filter-web-part-to-a-list-view-web-part-HA010250989.aspx) but filtering does not seem to be working the way it should. I think it has to do with the way the provider web part sends the filter values to the consumer or with the way these values are being compared.

1.- I created a Managed Metadata Column in my Announcements list

2.- I created a new User Profile property from Central Admin which also points to the same Term Set as my column in the Announcements list

3.- I connected both web parts using the link above and set up the Filter to "Send all values"

When I set the User Profile property to several values, Ex. "Tag B; Tag C" only items with "Tag B" in my Announcements list are displayed.

In other words:

Announcements list:

```
Title   Tags
Item 1  A;B
Item 2  C;D
Item 3  B
Item 4  E
Item 5  A
```

When User Profile property = "Tag B; Tag C" The announcements list gets filtered to:

```
Item 1
Item 3

but I want,

Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer: 
Only the first filter value will be considered by the consumer web part when filtering, which totally explains why items are being sorted by "Tag B" only.

Here you will find an interesting approach to this issue:
http://www.primordialcode.com/index.php/2009/09/02/wsssharepoint-create-custom-listviewwebpart/

Comment: given link is broken